# PyGame window not opening; no errors

Tags: python, pygame

I was using `pygame` for creating a shooter game and the code looks perfect  to me but my `pygame` window isn't opening. Here is my code:

```
#Modules
import pygame as py
#initialize
py.init()


#gameloop
running = True
while running:
    for event in py.event.get():
            if event.type == py.QUIT:
                running = False

 #screen
screen = py.display.set_mode((800,600))

#title
py.display.set_caption("Shooter")

#icon
icon = py.image.load("shooting-game.png")
py.display.set_icon(icon)

#player
icon2 = py.image.load("clipart1504254.png")
playerx = 889
playery = 493
def main():
    screen.blit(icon2, (playerx, playery))

#bg
screen.fill((252,0,0))
py.display.update()

main()
```

I am not getting any error but the window is not opening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The window wasn't showing because the screen only updates once, you need to move that and the `main()` function in the game loop.

Order matters in python. I moved some of your code into the while loop, and rearranged the code:

```
#Modules
import pygame as py
#initialize
py.init()

def main():
    screen.blit(icon2, (playerx, playery))


 #screen
screen = py.display.set_mode((800,600))

#title
py.display.set_caption("Shooter")

#icon
icon = py.image.load("shooting-game.png")
py.display.set_icon(icon)
icon2 = py.image.load("clipart1504254.png")

#player
playerx = 889
playery = 493

#gameloop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((252,0,0))
    main()
    py.display.update()
    for event in py.event.get():
            if event.type == py.QUIT:
                running = False
```

Also, for simple things like blitting an object, I wouldn't recommend a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop needs to be after defining the window.